# MySQL create table with STORAGE MEMORY clause

Tags: mysql, session, exception, storage, temp-tables

I encountered the following problem:
I have temporary table

```
CREATE temporary TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_GL_VAR
   (      
      G_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100)   DEFAULT '',
      G_DATE DATETIME,      
      G_ERROR_CODE INT   DEFAULT 0
   );
```

And I need to use it several times in single queries,for instance,

```
update t1 set c1 = (select G_TABLE_NAME from tmp_GL_VAR), c2 = (select G_ERROR_CODE from tmp_GL_VAR);
```

in functions with cursors, etc. However, in all these cases MySQL throws error:

> SQL Error(1137): Can't reopen table 'tmp_GL_VAR'.

Then I tried to create permanent table with STORAGE MEMORY clause (also tried ENGINE MEMORY clause), hoping that table will be cleaned when the session ends

```
CREATE TABLE GL_VAR
       (      
          G_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100)   DEFAULT '',
          G_DATE DATETIME,      
          G_ERROR_CODE INT   DEFAULT 0
       ) STORAGE MEMORY;
```

But unfortunately this option had no effect. The data was available across different sessions (connections).

Please advise how I can bypass 'Can't reopen table' without rewriting all queries, stored functions, etc. (there're far too many LOC).
The requirement is: table should be either dropped or at least truncated as session ends and the data from one session shouldn't be available in another session (each user can see only its own data in this table).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. there are problems http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/temporary-table-problems.html

```
You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query. For example, the following does not work:

mysql> SELECT * FROM temp_table, temp_table AS t2;
ERROR 1137: Can't reopen table: 'temp_table'
This error also occurs if you refer to a temporary table multiple times in a stored function under different aliases, even if the references occur in different statements within the function.
```

I think u should use usual table for this purpose.

And add some session identifier to make it work in your multi-user system. (Yes, u will have to add this identifier to ALL other queries using this table)

Delete rows by this identifier (or old timestamps if you want) any time u wish